# Configuring Hornetq core queue in Jboss standalone-full.xml

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I am trying to configure core-queue in Jboss-eap-6.4. But I cannot find a place (parent tag) to enter Hornetq core-queue configuration in `standalone-full.xml`.

I am aware that I can define core-queue in `hornetq-configuration.xml` as below

```
<queues>     
    <queue name="jms.queue.selectorQueue">
        <address>jms.queue.selectorQueue</address>
        <durable>true</durable>
    </queue> 
</queues>
```

What i want is to add this configuration in `standalone-full.xml`.
I tried to add above block in below tags. They give me errors saying invalid xml.

1. `<hornetq-server></hornetq-server>`
2. `<jms-destinations></jms-destinations>`

Can you specify where I should add the configuration in `standalone-full.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... after searching for hours, I did get the configuration from an another question. Required configuration for the `standalone-full.xml` is as below

```
<hornetq-server>
  .
  .

  <core-queues>     
    <queue name="jms.queue.selectorQueue">
      <address>jms.queue.selectorQueue</address>
      <durable>true</durable>
    </queue>
  </core-queues>
  .
  .
</hornetq-server>
```